# PagingToolBar bad display on BorderLayout and LayoutRegion

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am working with gxt and I have found the following problem.
In a ContentPanel where I add a PagingToolBar (as a bottonComponent) I have display problem: The Bar of the PagingToolBar is shown but all the icons appear on the right grouped in a displayable Menu. Is like if all the pagingToolabr is shifted to the right. 
This is happening only when the ContentPanel is inside a LayoutContainer with BorderLayout and LayoutRegion.Center or West,etc.

Anyone has faced this issue? Any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is simply to add a toolbar inside a border layout. No solution by now.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for with the following.

```
toolBar.setEnableOverflow(false);
```